# "Because it's her" vs "for her"

Tags: grammar

What is the correct formation of the sentence:

1. "She is going to Costa Rica for her honeymoon."
2. "She is going to Costa Rica because it's her honeymoon".

I believe it is the first one because the subject "it" is referring to is somewhat ambiguous. My friend disagrees and says both are correct.

Comment: Both are correct but they mean different things, or at least emphasize different aspects of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct.

> Why is she going to Costa Rica?
>
> Because she is going on her honeymoon / Because of her honeymoon / Because it's her honeymoon.

There's no ambiguity to the preposition "it" in this case - it refers to the cause, situation, condition, or motivation that prompted the question.

In rather stilted language:

> What is the situation that is causing her to go to Costa Rica?
>
> It is her honeymoon.

Answer (score 0):

You have spotted what looks like a possible syntactic ambiguity between *it* having an **antecedent** in the sentence, as in

> **[1a]** She is going to **Costa Rica** because *it*'s her country

and *it* acting instead as a dummy pronoun referring roughly to some situation, as in

> **[1b]** She is going to Costa Rica because *it*'s her honeymoon.

But there are two reasons why no actual ambiguity exists. The first is idiomatic. *It's her honeymoon* is a common locution for *She's taking her honeymoon vacation*. Secondly, no fluent speaker would consider that Costa Rica is a honeymoon, which would be required to interpret 1b like 1a.